# Raspberry tempdata to Thingspeak

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to send my temperature measurement from a DS18B20 connected to a Raspberry Pi, to Thingspeak. 
I have created a channel on Thingspeak for this project.

http://nergiza.com/como-hacer-un-registrador-de-temperatura-online-con-raspberry-pi/
I'm using the code from this link.

```
# Registrador de temperatura Nergiza.com
# python
import httplib, urllib, os, glob, time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')  
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')  
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'  
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]  
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'  

def read_temp_raw():  
    f = open(device_file, 'r')  
    lines = f.readlines()  
    f.close()  
    return lines

def read_temp():  
    lines = read_temp_raw()  
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':  
        time.sleep(0.2)  
        lines = read_temp_raw()  
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')  
    if equals_pos != -1:  
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]  
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0  
        return temp_c  

temperatura = read_temp()  
params = urllib.urlencode({'field1': temperatura, 'key':'Pon_aquí_tu_key'})  
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":  
    "text/plain"}  
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80")  
conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)  
response = conn.getresponse()  
print response.status, response.reason  
data = response.read()  
conn.close()
```

I have changed the key to my api_key from Thingspeak.
When i try to run this in terminal, it returns:

```
400 Bad Request
```

400 Bad Request is some kind of a bad syntax.
Thingspeak has an limit to receive data every 15 second.
But even adding  `time.sleep(16)` at the bottom this doesn't change anything.

I'm using a USB modem/stick.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

i'am using this simple code to send data to thingspeak from raspberry pi and this is working fine for me .try this ...

```
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
from time import sleep
import urllib2

DEBUG = 1
# Setup the pins we are connect to

#CONNECT OUT PIN 
co2pin = 16

#Setup API and delay
myAPI = ""
myDelay = 16 #how many seconds between posting data

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(co2pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


def Cotime(co2pin):
    co = 0  
    if (GPIO.input(co2pin) == True):
    co += 1
    return (str(co))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    baseURL = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=%s' % myAPI
    print baseURL

    while True:
    try:
        co = Cotime(co2pin)
        f = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL +"&field3=%s" % (co))
        print f.read()
        print 'Value Detected' +str(co)
        f.close()
        sleep(int(myDelay))
    except:
        print 'exiting.'
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a rookie mistake.
O was changed to an 0 in the API_Key.

Script works perfectly for DS18B20 and thingspeak.com